# Looking for PostMessage functionality in Qt

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt

The Win32 API has a `PostMessage` function that posts a message to the end of the GUI message queue to be processed later from the GUI thread, as opposed to `SendMessage` which sends and processes the message synchronous with the calling thread.

Is there a Qt solution for `PostMessage` functionality? A coworker suggested that Qt's server/socket implementation could provide it; is that a reasonable approach?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Check [QCoreApplication::postEvent()](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qcoreapplication.html#postEvent).

Comment: I'm accepting this answer because it closely emulates `PostMessage`, which is what I asked. However, I decided I am going to use jkerian's solution (QTimer::singleShot) because it better fits in with Qt's signals/slots. Thanks to you both!

Answer (score 7):

Look at [QTimer::singleShot](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.6/qtimer.html#singleShot).  In your case you'd want to use it with an `msec` value of `0`, which should provide the same functionality. (This is regularly used to implement delayed intialization, until the GUI event loop is running)

Answer (score 6):

Similar to the QTimer solution, but with the advantage that you can pass arguments, is the QMetaObject::invokeMethod way:

```
 QString SomeClass::compute(const QString&, int, double);
 ...
 QMetaObject::invokeMethod(obj, "compute", Qt::QueuedConnection,
                       Q_RETURN_ARG(QString, retVal),
                       Q_ARG(QString, "sqrt"),
                       Q_ARG(int, 42),
                       Q_ARG(double, 9.7));
```

The QueuedConnection queues it in the event loop, DirectConnection would execute it immediately.

Answer (score 4):

All answers so far are good, I just want to add that you can also use `connect()` with `Qt::QueuedConnection` for the connection type.